# Not showing TableView's items

Tags: android, tableview, tablerow

This is part of my code that must show the table view with several items, but it's not showing anything.

```
TableLayout tableView = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutUsers);
          TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
          LayoutParams rowLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
          tr.setLayoutParams(rowLayoutParams);

          TextView name = new TextView(this);
          name.setText(userClass.getUsername());
          LayoutParams dateLayParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // , LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
          name.setLayoutParams(dateLayParam);

          tr.addView(name);
          tableView.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          tr.setClickable(true);
```

What's the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Only one table row should be displayed on screen. All call refreshDrawableState() for table layout.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I don't see any rows, there are only white screen. How can I resolve that?

Comment: just try to replace tableView.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); with tableView.addView(tr,320,50); for temporarily if you see row in screen it means you need to change that paramerter. Also give some color to table row like blue/red so that u can able to identify

Answer (score 1):

Try: `name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: Thanks , but it didn't helped((

Comment: @HaykNahapetyan Try not setting any Layout parameters. This sometimes worked for me..

Comment: It didn't helped again(( , but I'll upvote your answer, Thank you very much

Comment: Hmm, well that's weird. It usually did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutUsers);

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setId(100 + 0);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Meenal");
    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    TableRow.LayoutParams imageParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();

    tr.addView(text);

    tr.setLayoutParams(params);
    tl.addView(tr, params);
```